# Java signature for Kotlin single-expression functions

Tags: java, kotlin, java-native-interface

I have several Kotlin methods I want to call from JNI.

With my current implementation, I have the following source on Kotlin side.

```
    var eventLayer: EventInterface? = null

    private fun onDisconnection(start: Boolean)  {
        eventLayer?.onDisconnection(start)
    }
```

The method signature is "onDisconnection(Z)V" and everything's working fine.

For such a simple method, I was thinking of using a single-expression function. Something like.

```
    var eventLayer: EventInterface? = null

    private fun onDisconnection(start: Boolean) = eventLayer?.onDisconnection(start)
```

When running my application, I have a (not so expected!) NoSuchMethod exception, and I checked the method signature which changed to "onDisconnection(Z)Ljava/lang/Void;"

Anyone to explain me this slight difference? And is there a way to have the same "(Z)V" signature with the single-expression function?

Thank you!

VR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of

```
private fun onDisconnection(start: Boolean) = eventLayer?.onDisconnection(start)
```

is whatever `eventLayer?.onDisconnection` returns.  This at least includes `null` because that's what it returns when `eventLayer` is null.

If you care about the return type of this function, then you should probably declare it.  Then you'll get a compiler error because null is not Unit.

I'm prett sure you could fix it like this:

```
private fun onDisconnection(start: Boolean) : Unit = 
    eventLayer?.onDisconnection(start) ?: Unit
```

... but it's pretty odd to use `=` with an expression that produces no value.  You should probably just write it with braces.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your help! Indeed with your help I found that using "private fun onDisconnection(start: Boolean) = eventLayer?.onDisconnection(start) ?: Unit" is working but I must say it makes the code not as readable as I thought. Keeping braces is the right solution!